# How to solve the following error in geom_errorbar: "requires the following missing aesthetics: x or xmin and xmax"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I create first a graph that shows the estimates of the coefficients of my outcome y. It works fine. Here is the code:

```
ggplot(pred, aes(y=y, fill= x2)) + 
  geom_col(aes(x1), position = "dodge")
```

However, when i try to add the geom_error bars as shown below, i get the following `Error: geom_errorbar requires the following missing aesthetics: x or xmin and xmax`. I am not sure what i am missing, can someone help?

```
ggplot(pred, aes(y=y, fill= x2)) + 
  geom_col(aes(x1), position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-sd, ymax=y+sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(y = c(0.164302489928412, 0.215532635370365, 0.164302489928412, 
0.131435285839938), x1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), x2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), sd = c(0.0148510153999744, 0.0141698339939684, 
0.0148510153999744, 0.0250010070315256)), row.names = c(NA, 4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: As the error message says you missed to specify an x aesthetic. Try with `geom_errorbar(aes(x = x1, ymin = ...)`.

Comment: Put `aes(x1)` in the initial call `ggplot(pred, aes(x = x1, y=y, fill= x2))`. You can then remove it from everywhere else, it's settled once and for the entire plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the name/variable you used for the x-values in your data (in your case x1 first: `geom_errorbar(aes(x1, ymin = y - sd, ymax = y + sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))`.
Worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: There appears to be some unmatched parenthesis in your answer. Also, try use triple backticks (`) before and after your code to format it as a code block.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).